# Backup AND RESTORE of viber messages

Tags: backup, restore, viber-messenger

Is there any free solution for backing up an restoring viber messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is old question but someone maybe still wonder how to do it now there is option to do that manually and automatically. Everything you have to need is that you are logged in with Google account, and simply go to viber >settings>account>viber backup, you can select a Google account on which you want backups to be stored and than choose how often you want backups or do that manually by pressing 'backup', there is also restore option and by the way restore option will be offered automatically when you install viber if Google account in use have backup on it. Here is a video of how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISWywTUB2-M

Answer (score 1):

**Backup Viber messages**

You can backup Viber messages using the built-in option by following the steps from this official Viber support webpage: [Viber | Create a backup file of your messages](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1334452-create-a-backup-file-of-your-messages#.VsWgpEJCJC0) .

> 1. Open Viber.
> 2. Select *More options*.
> 3. Select *Settings*.
> 4. Select *Calls and messages*.
> 5. Select *Email message history*. Tapping this option will create a backup file of all conversations present in the chat history.
> 6. Once the backup file is created, select the application through which you would like to email it and send it to yourself or any other email
>
> Messaging history backup is available on Android and iPhone only.

**Recover deleted Viber messages**

Login to your email account and download the attachment (backup file) to your SD card. Once you’ve done so, the backed up Viber messages cannot be restored onto your device directly.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but, those messages you can read as a text file, i wanted to restore messages directly in app, and as you said that isn't possible..